# MAPS API - application not running on the emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play-services

I'm verry new at android developement , i'm trying to make a map application but can't even show a simple map on a fragment .
I've followed many & many tutorials , search a lot of answers in stackoverflow but still can't get the result i want . 
I'm developping in eclipse and running app in emulator , i created a list of emulators to test on them but no one could show me the Map fragment. 
The current AVDs that i have now are:

- NEXUS S with ARMEABI V7 image system API 22
- NEXUS S with Google API's intel Atom 86 API 22
- Google NEXUS S with Google API's ARM API 22

All theese 3 don't have google play services and can't even install it on them (the tutorials i've watched not worked).
The last AVD that i could install Google play services in is the NEXUS S with ARM v7 image system **API 17**, i've google play services **12-5-18-000300-188802357** working fine and i've installed googleFrameWork and google play store(keep crashing even when update it )

The continious message i'm getting in this later is "Google play services are updating" ,everytime i try update the google play services , the app crash and stopped immediately .

This is my Manifest :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.algerlasmart"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

  <permission android:name="com.exemple.algerlasmart.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature">

 </permission>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACESS_NETWOK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission 
 android:name="com.exemple.algerlasmart.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/> 
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission 

 android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> 


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="12"
    android:targetSdkVersion="27" />


<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"

    />

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >

    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBBu2eJ-fSdlwUI9dPJhlbxK0emspboplQ"/>
    <meta-data 
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>




    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainInterface"
        android:label="@string/dashboard" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GetContact"
        android:label="@string/dashboard" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.exemple.fragments.Dummy"
        android:label="@string/dashboard" 
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="com.exemple.fragments.Dummy"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    </application>

 </manifest>
```

The Google play services library i've used is lib for API  22 (not worked) and i downgrade to lib r18 (old from google's repôsitories).

the XML file of my map is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/arroundMeLay"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/libele"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <fragment
    style="@style/mapViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" >
   </fragment>




</LinearLayout>
```

Please i've spend over a month stucking at these problems . 
**NOTE :** i've tried every time to update ,upgrade , downgrade SDK but still no answer or solution worked for me .